# scientific notation and non scientific notation values in one line

Tags: ada

This works:
Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line("Oil Rate : " & Float'Image(oil_float);
Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line(oil_float, Exp  => 0);

But this doesn't:
Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line("Oil Rate : " & Float'Image(oil_float, Exp  => 0) & " is " & (oil_float, Exp    => 0));

I wanted to put it in one line. is it possible?

Comment: What you say works doesn't compile.

Comment: Yes, it fails in compilation saying "named parameters not permitted for attributes"

Comment: Non-scientific notation is available when using the package Ada.Float_Text_IO;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write your own function:

```
function Float_Image (Value : Float; Exponent : Natural) return String is
   Result : String (1 .. 64);
begin
   Ada.Float_Text_IO.Put (Result, Value, Exp => Exponent);
   return Ada.Strings.Fixed.Trim (Result, Ada.Strings.Left);
end Float_Image;
```

(note the unfortunate fixed-length intermediate result; more than enough to hold `Float’Last`, though)